# Provide a custom error page for 401 (failed authorization)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization, custom-error-pages

I'm using Windows Authentication. The authentication works fine (the user is loaded with it's roles).

It's when authorization fails (using the `Authorize`) attribute that I want to provide a custom error page. It seems like the `HandleError` attribute only gets invoked for thrown exceptions but not for any error status codes (`>= 300`).

Custom errors section:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound/" />
  <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/Error/NotAuthorized/" />
</customErrors>
```

I got an `ErrorController` which returns views. But it do never get called.

Do I have to start throwing exceptions in a custom `Authorize` attribute to be able to handle 401, or is there a better MVC3 specific way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` in your `CustomAuthorize`

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary
                                         {
                                             {"area", ""},
                                             {"controller", "Error"},
                                             {"action", "NotAuthorized"},
                                             {"returnUrl", filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl}
                                         });
}
```

Comment: Sure. But that handling get's implementation specific since it can't be extended. I rather stick with my current solution: http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/06/asp-net-mvc3-custom-error-for-401-unauthorized/

Comment: @jgauffin I don't see any need for the exception since there isn't any code errors. you can redirect the user to your `NotAuthorized` Error page without exception so what is the point from throwing an exception  ??

Comment: I mixed up your solution with another one which generated the entire result in the custom authorize attribute.